# Worker Role goes down if there are no messages in the queue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I am getting a "object reference not set to an instance of an object" whenever I try to check if there are any messages in my queue..I believe maybe because my queue expires and goes down..

> msg = this.queue.GetMessage();
>                       if (msg != null)

This is my azure emulator error :

```
Diagnostics]: Error when reading control container:Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException: ERROR ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.EventHelper.ProcessWebResponse(WebRequest req, IAsyncResult asyncResult, EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.ControlChannel.GetControlContainer()
[Diagnostics]: Polling for configuration changes:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What I do on my OnStart method is  :

> ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;
>
> ```
>         // read storage account configuration settings
>         CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((configName,
> ```
>
> configSetter) =>
>               {
>                   configSetter(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName));
>               });
>               var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString");
>
> ```
>         // initialize blob storage
>         CloudBlobClient blobStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
>         this.container = blobStorage.GetContainerReference("userpictures");
>
>         // initialize queue storage 
>         CloudQueueClient queueStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
>         this.queue = queueStorage.GetQueueReference("pictureminiatures");
>         this.queue.CreateIfNotExist();
> ```

Could you help me spot where am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you check if `this.queue` variable is not null?

Comment: Are you only getting this error in the emulator?  The error you show is coming from Azure Diagnostics and is not related to your Queue.  What happens if you turn off Azure diagnostics in your project?

Comment: the this.queue variable is not null.. and the problem was that the azure emulator was not liking the debugging account that visual studio creates by default..:s I had to use my azure account and a certificate so that the emulator wont throw crap